# What the heck is the term for polygons that have the same number of sides (ie, or vertices)?

Tags: terminology, polygons

So, these guys are not congruent (in the usual usage of congruent) but they are both 7gons.

What is the term?

[image]

Would it be something to do with topology ?

In fact, are they "topologically identical" ... ?

(And if so, is there one word for that!)

Comment: I don't think there is such a general term. At least, not one I have come across.

Comment: It is a stretch and perhaps from another field of mathematics (graph theory), but **isomorphic** comes close. One can construct an equivalence class between the vertex set of polygon $A$ and polygon $B$ and it implies an equivalence class between the sides of polygons $A, B$.

Comment: @AdamRubinson - that's actually really amazing! I suspected that may be the case, but did not want to appear stupid in front of pros.

Comment: @vvg that's actually brilliant, thank YOU.

Comment: @vvg Sure, but I don't see any benefit to saying what you've said over saying, "If shape A and B have the same number of sides, then..."

Comment: @AdamRubinson Yes, I agree.

Comment: If you're saying it would be beneficial if we had one word rather than a phrase for this because one word is shorter and you spend less time saying it, then yes I agree with you. What I was saying in my previous comment was that the term "isomorphic" does not tell you that the two shapes have the same number of sides. Only the phrase "isomorphic up to number of sides" would tell you what is meant. Because *isomorphism* just means "similar in some way, which I'll now be specific about..." So saying those two terms are isomorphic doesn't tell you *what property* is isomorphic about them.

Comment: Ah, sorry understood now @AdamRubinson - yes a great point

Comment: If you have time pls note my edit re "topology" , @AdamRubinson and vvg !

Comment: You mean homeomorphic? Might be - I'm not sure.